# Getting Runtime Exception: Unable to destroy activity while closing the Flutter app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, kotlin

> Getting this error (RunTimeException) on the back press from the Main Screen.

> Using Navigation back button to close the app.

> Earlier it is working but now the exception is thrown.

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5056)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5085)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.servertransaction.DestroyActivityItem.execute(DestroyActivityItem.java:44)      
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)      
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7592)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter activity
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.lyokone.location.FlutterLocationService.setActivity(Unknown Source:2)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.deinitialize(LocationPlugin.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.detachActivity(LocationPlugin.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at com.lyokone.location.LocationPlugin.onDetachedFromActivity(LocationPlugin.java:69)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.detachFromActivity(FlutterEnginePluginRegistry.java:346)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.onDetach(FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate.java:512)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity.onDestroy(FlutterActivity.java:577)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.Activity.performDestroy(Activity.java:8180)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnDestroy(Instrumentation.java:1342)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity(ActivityThread.java:5041)
E/AndroidRuntime( 4154):        ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please format error output (put in ``` on top and bottom of error message) and provide more info about what are you using on app's dismiss.

Comment: Are you calling methods or have a functionality in `onDestroy` method?

Comment: No. Earlier it is working fine but now this error is coming.

Comment: Are you added new plugins to the project?

Answer (score 1):

#### Resolved by updating the version of "location" package in pubspec.yaml file